# Genereic class and static generic method

Tags: java, generics

I'm writing generic class

```
public class SomeClass<T> {

    public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T min(Collection<? extends T> c) {
        T min = c.iterator().next();
        for (T element : c)
            if (element.compareTo(min) < 0)
                min = element;
        return min;
    }

}

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SomeClass<Integer>.min(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)); // compile-time error
        SomeClass.min(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3)); // ok
    }

}
```

In generic class `SomeClass` and generic method `SomeMethod` type-parameter `T` is the same or defference?

Why we have compile time-error on the string `SomeClass<Integer>.min(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));`?

Comment: what's the compile-time error?

Comment: @newacct Error description is `';' excepted not a statement`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class declaration

```
public class SomeClass<T>
```

defines a generic class, where `<T>` specifies the type parameter (also called type variable). This introduces the type variable, `T`, that can be used anywhere inside the class.

And the method declaration:

```
public static <T extends Comparable<? super T>> T min(Collection<? extends T> c) {
...
}
```

defines a `generic method`. Generic methods are methods that introduce their own type parameters. This is similar to declaring a generic type, but the type parameter's scope is limited to the method where it is declared.

Now if you want to call the generic method `min`, you need to call:

```
SomeClass.<Integer>min(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));
```

Comment: I'm already realize this. What about my second question? _Why we have compile time-error on the string SomeClass<Integer>.min(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));?_ I was thinking that it is true, because i'm trying to invoke method of generic class.

Comment: Yes, and i want to understand why we compiler doesnt allow to write `SomeClass<Integer>.min(Arrays.asList(1,2,3));`?

Comment: @Dmitrii That is because you have put the type parameter before the `.`.  That is wrong; since you want to provide a parameter for the method not the class.  You provide a type parameter after the class name when specifying a type, for example when you declare a variable.

Answer (score 0):

It's different, and you should never write code like this, specifically because of the possibility for confusion.  Always use different type variables on classes and methods inside those classes.

Comment: Type-parameter T in method `min` visible in the method's body only?

Comment: And what about second question: Why `SomeClass<Integer>.min(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));` is not valid?  I'm just trying to invoke the static method min.

Comment: The brackets should go on the other side of the dot: `SomeClass.<Integer>min(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3))`.  You must not provide generic arguments to classes when you're invoking their static methods.

Answer (score 0):

T is for Type and you are accessing static method which has nothing to do with T.

Either use like this

```
SomeClass<Integer> a = new SomeClass<Integer>();
a.min(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

**OR**

```
SomeClass.min(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));
```

Answer (score 0):

The two `T`s are different: the fist one is a parameter for the class (and is unused) and the second one is specific to the method. Since the method is static, the class parameter doesn’t affect it.

When you write `SomeClass<Integer>.min(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));`, you get an error because it doesn’t make sense to add a parameter to `SomeClass` since no object of that class is instanciated. `SomeClass` is only used to tell the compiler that you want to call a static method from that class. You can add a parameter to the *method* with `SomeClass.<Integer>min(Arrays.asList(1, 2, 3));`, but you don't have to since the compiler can infer the type here.

Answer (score 0):

So what the compile message told you was that it's a syntax error. Why it's invalid syntax is easy to understand. You are trying to call a method on a type. That means you are calling a static method. Static methods are not within the scope of generic type parameters. So it is not allowed to put a generic type argument on the left side.

If you want the technical reason, it's because your method call expression is not [one of the forms that's allowed by the syntax](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-15.html#jls-15.12). The closest form to yours is `TypeName . NonWildTypeArguments Identifier ( ArgumentListopt )`. But `TypeName` (which is defined [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se7/html/jls-6.html#jls-6.5)) must be an identifier or package-qualified identifier. It does not allow brackets.

Comment: Thanks for exhaustive answer!